# Which statement in my main method is calling all my other methods in my other classes and my main class?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, jframe, program-entry-point

**Question:** Ok, so this is going to sound slightly confusing due to my lack of total understanding on the subject. Currently, I am creating a game following a youtube tutorial (to understand the basics of game development in java).

After following some of the tutorials, I am confused as to what is the real purpose of the main method and the class that contains it. I thought that the main method's job was to call all the methods of its own class and the desired methods in other classes. However in my main method in my main "Game" class, here is all I have:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    game.start();
}
```

Does `frame.add(game)` (`game` is an instance of `Game`) "call" all the other methods in other classes? **Whatl the exactly does `frame.add()` do?** Also, I am still trying to understand threads despite reading a lot of explanations. **When I write `game.start();` to "start" the thread, what exactly does this imply?** Does it call all the methods in the game class only?

Here is my thread code if its needed:

```
private synchronized void start() {
    if(running) {
        return;
    } else {
        running = true; 
    }
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
public synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running) {
        return;
    } else {
        running = false;
    }
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit((0));
}
```

Here are the variables I initialized:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8921419424614180143L;
public static final int WIDTH = 640;
public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 4*3;
public static String title = "Game";
public static Game game = new Game();
public static GameState state = GameState.MENU;
private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;
private Renderer gfx; 
public static Game getInstance(){
```

***I am just unsure of how all other methods in the game class and my other classes are being called if this is all I have in my main method.*** Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I am really struggling here as you can probably tell.

Comment: Go through basic Java tutorials first.

Comment: I have gone through basic java tutorials. I am taking an AP class after an introductory course last year. I started off by creating a blackjack game that works well. However, that was without a GUI. Now I am trying to learn GUI (for 2 months now) because they don't teach it at my school. @PM77-1

Comment: Wrong choice of sample code maybe. That thread code is a bit special, why (when using a thread) not a daemon thread for instance. Must be done purely for that specific gaming.

Comment: I guess you are right. Always think I can get answers on here and then i butcher the wording and get bashed.. :( lol. Thanks for the advice, @JoopEggen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `main()` method is to give an entry point for stand alone execution.

In your case (you did not show how `game` is initialized but I guess it was a `static Game game = new Game();` initialized field) what happens is that first the static fields are initialized (which will call the `Game()` constructor).

Then the main method is started. It will set the initialized `game` as the content of the frame (which means the `Frame` will call various UI related methods like `paint()` from that moment on. Threading in Gui is a quite complicated topic, but for the sake of your question you can ignore it).

The rest of the methods in main are used to set up the containing frame. That's unusual for bigger applications but quite common for such small examples. (It does cause methods on game being called, for example for layout or drawing).

So finally main calls `game.start()` (which is the `start()` method on Game you have shown). It does create a new thread, which executes (by definition) the `run()` method on the `Runable` given to the `new Thread(this)` constructor (`this`, which is at this point the same instance as `game`).

Comment: "...which executes (by convention) the run() method..."  Convention has nothing to do with it.  A new thread _always_ starts in the `run()` method.  That's how the standard library works.  You can't change it.  If the Thread is an instance of the base Thread class (e.g, as in the example above) then `Thread.run()` calls the `run()` method of the Thread's Runnable delegate or, if there is no delegate, it just returns.

Comment: replace convention with definition.

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` method is like any other method with respect to what it executes. Only what you explicitly execute (call) will be executed.

There is no method to automatically call all the other methods, because there is no purpose for such method. If, for some weird reason, you want such a method, just write it and from within it, do call the other methods.

A thread is a separate execution path in your program. When you call start() it begins and practically it goes to its special run() method, which is executed in parallel.

Any good introductory Java book should have detailed explanations to your questions.

Comment: I think the idea that `run()` is _special_ only helps to confuse newbies.  The only thing that's special about `run()` is that the library calls it when a new thread is started.  But that's a property of the library, not really a property of the run() method itself.  A run() method that you write in your own code is no different from any other method that you write in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answers that get at your bolded questions are:

1. `frame.add(...)` adds a component (like a button or label) to a frame or panel.
2. `game.start()` creates a new thread and calls the `run()` method of the game class in that thread.
3. So other methods you've written are called from `game.run()`. If they aren't in there (and they aren't in `main(...)`), they aren't being called.

I have to agree with the comment from PM77 though. It sounds like you're beginning in java, and Threading and GUIs are both pretty complex topics. There are basic games you can design (ie tic-tac-toe) that don't require either of them. Try those out before you tackle something as challenging as this.